# Intercepting all ajax requests - Bad practise?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

[This post](http://qnimate.com/monitoring-ajax-requests/) shows a way to monitor and intercept all ajax requests:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(value) {
    this.addEventListener("progress", function(){
        console.log("Loading");
    }, false);
    this.realSend(value);
};
```

Clean and simple, and no need for jQuery or similar. I can't find anything wrong with this, but my gut feeling tells me that it can be dangerous to hook in to the XMLHttpRequest like this. Should this be avoided, or is it ok to use?

Comment: Since this doesn't actually change the functionality, and it calls the original method, i'd have to go with, yes, it's safe to use. Ignoring the fact that some older browsers don't support addEventListener or XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Dangerous - yes if you have a mistake in it then it blows up everything, not just your code. OK - yes if you know what you're doing. Better would be however to use a wrapper if you can get all components to use it.

Comment: @Bergi: Could you elaborate on what you mean by a wrapper?

Comment: Don't overwrite the native `.send` method. Expose your intercepting one as a different method, or put it on a different object (which delegates the other method calls; being a [decorated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) object effectively).

Comment: Sure, that would probably be best. Unfortunately, in the case I am working on I am not in control of the rest of the website. I need to monitor what happens on the page, but I have not found any suitable events that I can listen to.